# How to send multiple data to server using for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        product_option_id: 1,
        quantity: 2,
      }),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        if (result.success) {
          goToCart();
        } else {
          alert('error');
        }
      });
  };
```

I have a question regaring sending data to backend using fetch.
I have product_option_id in array format as result = [4, 3] for example.
And I have quantity in array format as count = [1, 2] for example accordingly. So here I have product_option_id: 4 and its quantity is 1 and I also have product_option_id: 3 and its quantity is 2. If I have to send these data separately one after another one as above instead of sending array, can I write an if statement like this in body?

```
fetch('', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        for (let i =0; i < result.length; i++) {
        product_option_id: result[i],
        quantity: count[i],
        }
      }),
    })
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(result.map((el, index) => ({
product_option_id: el,
quantity: count[index]
})))`.

You can `map` your array to produce an array of objects with your custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, an overview of your objective. You have the following data structures:

```
const result = [6, 7, 8];
const count = [1, 2, 3];
```

... and you want to send them to the server as an array of objects like:

```
[
    { "product_option_id": 6, "quantity": 1 },
    { "product_option_id": 7, "quantity": 2 },
    { "product_option_id": 8, "quantity": 3 }
]
```

To do this, you are on the right lines, but you can't use a `for` loop inside another line. Try replacing your 'for' with a call to Array.map() as follows:

```
function transform(result, count) {
    return result.map((r, index) => ({
        product_option_id: r,
        quantity: count[index] || 0
    });
}

const submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(transform(result, count)),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        if (result.success) {
            goToCart();
        } else {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
};
```

I refactored your code into smaller functions to make it easier to read for the benefit of anyone reading this, but you could call result.map inline inside your original function.